# U.K. Employment post contract, can they do this?

Tags: contracts

I worked for a company who employed me as a software engineer. They had a temporary contract and I completed the project, they didn't find a purpose for me so they let me go.

On my "Exit Interview" they showed a makeshift contract that basically said that in regards to the project AND other duties I am to do these free of charge (basically, forever) since I was the only one on the project and the only developer there I told them no I would not accept those conditions and they did not say anything else.

Moving down the line a few months later, the client who we did the project is having problems, obviously the client is paying them but they have contacted me and said I MUST do the work. I refused as I now have another job. Their "lawyer" is claiming that:

I do not need to have signed the contract as long as the contract was handed to me.

I am at a loss of what to do, I know this is a law question but what are the implications of just ignoring this?

Comment: Sorry, we honestly can't answer legal or company policy questions.

Comment: @Christopher Estep - hypothetically - what would you do?

Comment: @Uninvited, this site isn't really used for "hypotheticals", but if I were you, I'd be contacting a lawyer.

Comment: You need to contact a lawyer. I don't expect it'll cost too much/take too much time for him to write a letter that tells them what they can do with their demand. And if it protects from costly litigation, it's money well spent.

Comment: They told you that it doesn't matter if you didn't sign (or conceivably even verbally agree) to the contract, you're still obligated to its terms? I don't know anything about UK law (and as the previous commenters said, contact a lawyer), but this is the most ridiculous thing I've heard all day.

Comment: The Citizens' Advice Bureau offers excellent (and free) employment law advice. I highly recommend a discussion with them. If you have a copy of that contract take it along.

Comment: Were you a permeant employee or were you a sub contractor?

Comment: I do not know of any judge would enable them to make people work for free. It is against the minimum wage for a start. Tell them to sling their hook. Their lawyer is not a lawyer and they are trying a fast one.

Comment: You have nothing to worry about, their 'lawyer' explicitly stated that you refused to sign it... I'd just ignore it... nothing signed, = no contractual obligations. He's not a real lawyer or he would not have admitted that in writing. If they push it, they will lose and you'll get damages and probably more. If I did bother to answer it would be "No idea what you're on about, see you in court, have a nice day." But answering at all is a bad move, it opens a dialogue which is a waste of time. You can't say anything wrong if you don't say anything.

Comment: Excuse me while I write up some contracts to do my housework, yard work, and odd jobs free of charge, and start handing them out. It will save a lot of money each month compared to negotiating with contractors.

Comment: "I do not need to have signed the contract as long as the contract was handed to me." - Indeed, you don't need to sign a contract just because it was handed to you. Since you didn't sign it, you are not bound by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If their "lawyer" is a "lawyer" and not a lawyer, then they are in trouble. Pretending to be a lawyer when you are not is *deep* trouble. With his claim that "I do not need to have signed the contract as long as the contract was handed to me. ", it seems he may be a "lawyer"

Ignoring this is never a good idea.

You might write a letter stating that you absolutely refute that you have any obligations towards them, that you especially refute that you have any obligation to do any work for them for free, that you refute that you have signed any contract that would produce such an obligation, and that they should either within 7 days respond and agree with what you stated, or to provide any reasons and / or evidence that this would be otherwise, which you will then hand over to your lawyer.

Obviously make a copy of everything, and go to your post office for recorded delivery since these jokers can obviously not be trusted.

Or you might go directly to a lawyer. But don't ignore it. Not responding and not contradicting them might be interpreted against you.

PS. Opinion on law.stackexchange.com is that if the "lawyer" pretends to be a lawyer that could in the worst case get him jail time, and if the company tries to trick you into working for free that could in the worst case be fraud and get someone jail time. Look up the question "Pretending to be a lawyer" there.